# VirtualKeyboard.geometrychange event is not fired in some Android Chromium browsers (Opera, Samsung)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile, chromium

I try to implement a JS script that detects when the users opens a virtual keyboard on their Android device. Now it looks like this:

```
function detectVirtualKeyboardOpeningViaAPI(e) {
    try {
        console.log('entered keyboard opening listener');

        const { x, y, width, height } = e.target.boundingRect;

        console.log('keyboard bounding rect received via API');

        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            console.log('keyboard opening detected via API');
        } else {
            console.log('keyboard has zero dims in API');
        }
    } catch(exc) {
        console.log('detectVirtualKeyboardOpeningViaAPI: ' + exc.message);
    }
}

if ("virtualKeyboard" in navigator) {
    try {
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;      
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.addEventListener("geometrychange", e => detectVirtualKeyboardOpeningViaAPI(e));
        console.log('keyboard: API listener added');
    } catch(exc) {
        console.log('Virtual keyboard available, bind: ' + exc.message);
    }
} else {
    // some fallback code
}
```

In Android Chrome 120 and Android Edge 119 it works as expected, ending up with 'keyboard opening detected via API' message when I opent the virtual keyboard; but in Opera 79 and Samsung Browser 23 the final output is 'keyboard: API listener added', which means that the listener is successfully attached, but `geometrychange` event is never triggered, although MDN says that both these browsers shall support this event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard/geometrychange_event#browser_compatibility

Any suggestions to debug the event and fix this issue are welcome.

Comment: @James , Opera on left is desktop Opera. There also is Opera Android that reports minimal supported version of 66.